# sed to replace line which contains space wildcards

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed

I have file which has 1500 line and I want to change line number 1449 I know I can use below command

```
sed -i '1449s/"'$' == $rdn{ strlen($rdn) - 1 })"/'$' == $rdn[ strlen($rdn) - 1 ])/' file_name
```

but it's not working. I want to replace

```
'$' == $rdn{ strlen($rdn) - 1 })
```

to

```
'$' == $rdn[ strlen($rdn) - 1 ])
```

Anyone knows how to replace this with specifying line number in sed, please guide.

Comment: What's the text you want to replace, and what do you want it to become?

Comment: @roaima I just wants to replace {  to [ for that particular line , and Philippos answered helped me

Comment: Oh I see. Your single line of code isn't actually the line at all. I've fixed that for you now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not the line number nor `sed`, it's the quoting: You can't nest double quotes inside single quotes, so `'1449s/"'` has matching single quotes, thus your script starts with `1449s/"$ ==` and so on.

Your pattern is probably unique without the `'$'`, so you could work with single quotes only:

```
sed -i '1449s/ == $rdn{ strlen($rdn) - 1 })/ == $rdn[ strlen($rdn) - 1 ])/' file_name
```

Or you put the whole thing inside double quotes, but need to escape the `$` from your shell:

```
sed -i "1449s/'\$' == \$rdn{ strlen(\$rdn) - 1 })/'\$' == \$rdn[ strlen(\$rdn) - 1 ])/" file_name
```

Or finally, if the line doesn't contain any `{` or `}` except the ones to be replaced, you can use the `y` command:

```
sed -i '1449y/{}/[]/' file_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed  -i -e "1449s/})$/])/g" -e "1449s/{ strlen/[ strlen/g" filename
```

output

```
'$' == $rdn[ strlen($rdn) - 1 ])
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).